# Django1.11 AttributeError at /login/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: python, django

I am writing a login page with Django 1.11. Somehow I received this message

> AttributeError at /login/

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'**

My code is as below

```
def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')

    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
```

And here is my template

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="username">用戶名稱:</label>{% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{username}}" id="username"><br />
        <label for="password">用戶密碼:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="登入" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: change `if user is None and user.is_active:` to `if user and user.is_active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do `is_active` on a **None object** that's why getting error. It should be

```
if user is not None and user.is_active:
```

So, if **user is not none and if it is active** then login and send to **index** page.

Answer (score 2):

An object returns true if exists so you can change your logic

```
if user and user.is_active
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is broken. It should be `if user is not None and user.is_axtive`.